# Finding unique items in the array

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, array

I was reading this [code](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/array-unique/blob/master/index.js) where author claims that its the fastest implementation which I doubt, hence I decided to write my version of the same problem.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function unique(arr) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
    throw new TypeError('array-unique expects an array.');
  }
  return arr.filter(function(element, index) {
    return arr.indexOf(element) === index;
  });
};
```

The above code looks readable to me but I don't about its performance(I think mine should be faster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is elegant, clean, easy to read.

The other is less so, but there is a significant difference between the two: your version returns a new array of unique values, the other removes duplicate values, modifying the input array.

Both algorithms are \$O(n^2)\$. Your implementation includes one redundant comparison per element: when the `indexOf` call reaches the current element, it compares it to itself, which is a redundant comparison for your ultimate intent of finding unique values. The other implementation optimized this with the `var j = i + 1;` step: it compares the current element to all subsequent element, never to itself.

In the end, the performance difference will come down to the implementation of `splice` and new array creation of the given JavaScript engine. I don't think such comparison will be very useful, except in very rare extreme cases. Also keep in mind that *premature optimization is the root of all evil*. And once again, there's also the matter of the different behavior of the implementations (return new unique array or mutate the parameter in-place), which makes comparisons problematic.

For what it's worth, in cases when an \$O(n^2)\$ solution to this problem is good enough (as opposed to an \$O(n)\$ solution using \$O(n)\$ extra space), I would go for your version, because it's intuitively easier to read.

Comment: Just out of curiosity `redundant comparison` with single element is that bad?

Comment: It's good to avoid redundant operations when possible, but not at all cost. Sometimes eliminating a redundant operation takes significant effort and the result is significantly more complex and hard to read.

Comment: As you know I have been greatly benefited by your answers, can you please recommend me some books which helped you most or you think may help me. I know its off topic but I am leaving it on you :)

Comment: Glad to help! Code Complete (2nd edition) by Steve McConnell is my bible =) It's a big book, if you're a bit impatient, then start with chapters 33, 3, 5, 6, 7, 20, 23, and then the rest.

Comment: Looking after my own solution after months, is it a good idea to pass a comparator function which checks equality of custom object on some key?